# Как сделать респонсив-svg по одной из осей?

Tags: html, css, svg, responsive

Собственно, если svg задать `viewBox`, то он масштабируется, подгоняя свой размер под контейнер. Но я хочу, чтобы он только по горизонтальной оси масштабировался, а по вертикальной изменял высоту без внутреннего масштабирования.

В сниппете одинаковая svg-разметка помещена в div'ы разного размера. В первой секции отображение сделано только с помощью стилей, а во второй атрибут `viewBox` изменяется скриптом, чтобы показать, какой результат я хочу получить.

Обращаю внимание, что высота зелёного прямоугольника совпадает с шириной синих, т. е. растягивание без сохранения пропорций не подходит.

```js
var divs = document.querySelectorAll(".expected div");

for (var q=0; q<divs.length; ++q) { debugger
  var d = divs[q];
  var svg = d.querySelector("svg");
  svg.setAttribute("viewBox", "0 0 10 " + 10 * d.clientHeight / d.clientWidth);
}
```

```css
svg { display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; }
div { display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; border: 1px dotted red; }
section + section { margin-top: 1em; }

.a { width: 12em; height: 12em; }
.b { width: 4em; height: 8em; }
.c { width: 8em; height: 4em; }
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="a">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 10 10">
      <rect x="0" y="50%" width="100%" height="50%" fill="silver" />
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="1" height="100%" fill="blue" />
      <rect x="9" y="0" width="1" height="100%" fill="blue" />
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="10" height="1" fill="green" />
    </svg>
  </div>
  <div class="b">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 10 10">
      <rect x="0" y="50%" width="100%" height="50%" fill="silver" />
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="1" height="100%" fill="blue" />
      <rect x="9" y="0" width="1" height="100%" fill="blue" />
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="10" height="1" fill="green" />
    </svg>
  </div>
  <div class="c">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 10 10">
      <rect x="0" y="50%" width="100%" height="50%" fill="silver" />
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="1" height="100%" fill="blue" />
      <rect x="9" y="0" width="1" height="100%" fill="blue" />
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="10" height="1" fill="green" />
    </svg>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="expected">
  <div class="a">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 10 10">
      <rect x="0" y="50%" width="100%" height="50%" fill="silver" />
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="1" height="100%" fill="blue" />
      <rect x="9" y="0" width="1" height="100%" fill="blue" />
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="10" height="1" fill="green" />
    </svg>
  </div>
  <div class="b">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 10 10">
      <rect x="0" y="50%" width="100%" height="50%" fill="silver" />
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="1" height="100%" fill="blue" />
      <rect x="9" y="0" width="1" height="100%" fill="blue" />
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="10" height="1" fill="green" />
    </svg>
  </div>
  <div class="c">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 10 10">
      <rect x="0" y="50%" width="100%" height="50%" fill="silver" />
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="1" height="100%" fill="blue" />
      <rect x="9" y="0" width="1" height="100%" fill="blue" />
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="10" height="1" fill="green" />
    </svg>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: А обязательно это делать на чистом SVG?

Comment: @AlexeyTen, а какие предложения? Прямоугольники - это чисто для примера.

Comment: Как-то так http://dabblet.com/gist/8d08d6767737b29683869bd6436fdc2d

Comment: @AlexeyTen, конкретно так не годится, но идея интересная. А ещё я не знал, что можно вкладывать svg в svg.

Comment: @Qwertiy теперь перфекционист в тебе должен страдать (77776), по теме - я меняю viewbox из js

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, не понял.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте `CSS`:

```
img{
   display:block;
   max-width:100%;
   height:auto;
}
```

Comment: Как это вообще к вопросу относится? Там ни одного тега img в коде нет.

Comment: @Qwertiy ну замени на svg, в чем разница? Это такое же изображение. Можешь так же попробовать: width: 100%; height: auto;

Есть тема хорошая по этому поводу: https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/

Comment: Нет, не такое же. Можешь проверить.